# how to design 2D Rubic grid square in android that can be scrolled horizontally and vertically

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-xml, android-scrollview

i need some help with the design in android.
i want to make a ui that looks like this
[image]
fig1 is the actual ui i want to achieve,
c1,c2,c3 represent columns and r1,r2,r3 represent rows.

1. when i scroll r1 horizontally i want position 1 to shift to position 2, position 2 will shift to position 3, position 3 will shift to position 1. as shown in fig:2
2. when i scroll vertically for example c1, position 1 will shift to position 4, position 4 will shift to position 7 and position 7 will shift to position1 as shown in fig:3

Comment: this is called shifting not scrolling

Comment: please ask a specific problem. don't ask for the code of the whole problem/assignment/project.

Answer (score 0):

Just texturemap it onto a torus, then zoom into a 3x3 part of it and rotate it based on the x,y positions of the screen. Here's an example I did for a computer science prof with link to a free arcore app:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0clY_dbjIqI